# C# Encoding.GetEncodingのShift_JISの指定方法について

Tags: c#

タイトルの件、ファイル読み込みで文字コードを指定する際
下記のように文字コードを指定するかと思います。

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")
```

Shift_JISを指定したい場合、shift-jisとShift_JISでは
どちらを指定すれば良いでしょうか？

何か違いがありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

国際化を考慮した際に常にShift_JISが求められているのか、それとも利用者のデフォルト言語が求められているのかを判断する必要があります。
後者の場合、[`Encoding.Default`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.8)を使用すべきです。

その上で、[`Encoding`クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8)のページには`shift_jis`とあるためそれが妥当な選択肢と思われます。